Generated Code Compilation issue in spark application
I am writing spark application which has dependency on iceberg-core module of Apache Iceberg Project. Following is my sample code snippet
 Dataset<Snapshot> snapshotDataset = spark.createDataset(
        TableMetadataParser.read(fileIO, metadataLocation).snapshots(),
        Encoders.bean(Snapshot.class));
 Dataset<Snapshot> snapshotDataset = spark.createDataset(
        TableMetadataParser.read(fileIO, metadataLocation).snapshots(),
        Encoders.bean(Snapshot.class));

While running application in Intellij IDE, I am hitting following exception which I am unable to resolve
Driver stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: 
Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4) (192.168.1.11 executor driver): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: 
File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 45: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: 
File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 45: Unknown variable or type "org.apache.iceberg.Snapshot$.MODULE$"
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.waitForValue(LocalCache.java:3620)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.waitForLoadingValue(LocalCache.java:2362)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2251) 

I have hunch that the issue could be with the field of Snapshot class which is non serializable, Any Idea How to resolve such exceptions in this case as I don't have control over the source code of this dependency
